# Example to definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, direct-sum, direct-product

A direct sum decomposition is $S=\bigoplus_{a \ge 0} S_a$ (d is degree of forms homegeneous polynomial). I try to find and example of this definition, because I need to understand it.
Can I take polynomial: $F_1=1+x_0^2+x_1+x_0x_3$, where $S=\mathbb{R[x_0,x_1,x_2]}$?
$S_0= 1$, $S_1=x_1$, $S_2=x_0^2 +x_0x_3$. Is it correct or no? Is it wrong? When no could you explain why and give me better example?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you! Can the notation be written any better? @red_trumpet